# Wrapping my mind around MEF: how to load View(Model)?

Tags: mvvm, prism, mef, loading

I'm learning prism V4 using MEF to load my modules. Loading modules does work, but in one module I want to load a View/ViewModel (MVVM) and don't really know how I get MEF to resolve all this stuff for me.

First: how do I need to mark the ViewModel (I follow the StockTraderRI example) so it is not loaded on startup but instead can be loaded during runtime into a region?

Second: how do I load the ViewModel using MEF so it gets connected to the corresponding interfaces?

MEF does this very nicely for things on startup which are marked as [Export], but I got no idea how to achieve this during runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use what is known as a [Lazy Export](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lazy%20Exports) so that the interface is not resolved until you explicitly use it.

---

If you need to create multiple instances, MEF doesn't support this particularly well.  You can either do your own discovery and instantiation, or you can define the Export like this:

```
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
[Export(typeof(ISomething)]
public class Something : ISomething { }
```

The downside is that now wherever you need to create the instance, you need to have a reference to the actual Container instance.  Then you can do:

```
var something = _container.GetExportedObject<ISomething>();
```

---

EDIT: Okay, I think I understand better what you're after.  Here is how I've typically resolved this issue:

1. I implement my View objects as UserControl instances and don't set a DataContext anywhere in their code or XAML.
2. I create a DataTemplate that binds from the Type of the ViewModel to the UserControl.
3. On my MainViewModel (or whatever corresponds to the View hosting the regions), I expose a general RegionX Object (possibly typed to an interface if all of my ViewModels will share some common functionality, but Object works fine).
4. I create a ContentPresenter with Content bound to the RegionX property.
5. Now my MainViewModel can import different ViewModel instances corresponding to the types of ViewModels that might be hosted by the RegionX.  When I want to switch the 'active' View in the region, I simply set RegionX to the corresponding ViewModel.

Comment: I was more looking for something like MefMagic.Create<MyViewModel> which would create the MyView needed?

Comment: Are you looking to create multiple instances of the same type?

Comment: No (at least not yet). The View/ViewModel should be created and somehow welded together.

Comment: As I said: it works like charm when the view is automagically loaded into the proper region. Now I just like to know how to pull this off by hand when I want to load some other view/viewmodel into some region.

Comment: I'm just looking for something like "container.resolve<myViewModel>" which will give me anything to set into the region (at least I already got the regionmanager).

Comment: Uhm, where do you get _container? Or, at least, what type is it?

Comment: @Sam, _container is the CompositionContainer you created at startup to host all of your Exported Parts.  This is the unfortunate side to that approach, as now you need to pass your container around.  One approach is to create a static host class where different parts of your application can get to the container.  Basically you're back to the old Service Locator pattern, with a central location to request instances.

Comment: Ah, so thats "Container" from the MefBootstrapper class? I was searching for something like IRegionManager to be used as constructor parameter, no wonder I found nothing.

Comment: @Sam, I haven't actually used Prism, but now that I looked at the documentation, I think what you probably want is MefServiceLocatorAdapter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.mefextensions.mefservicelocatoradapter_members%28v=PandP.38%29.aspx

Comment: You might be right - but I got no idea how to use it. Dang, I really need to learn more about prism/mef, so far it is very confusing. Not in the broad scope, but in the details. Thanks so far!

Comment: Ah yes, using the MefBootstrapper.Container I got it to work, this seems to be the missing link I was searching for - still got no idea what the MefServiceLocatorAdapter is useful for, maybe so I don't need to remember the Container in a global var?

Comment: @Sam, my guess is that the MefServiceLocatorAdapter somehow ties into Prism in some standard way it provides a service locator, but I'm not really sure.  It's very likely implemented by keeping a reference to the default Container around.